# Extract logic applied in a sequence of integers

Tags: beginner, algorithm, haskell

I've done it in C# before but thought that a functional language would be a good fit for this kind of thing.

From this ascending list of integers:

> [100,103,106,112,118,121]

I had to calculate the difference between two consecutive numbers and group them while the result doesn't change. The final output must be a `string` like this:

> "(group.length x difference)+(next group.length + next diff)+.."

Note that a same difference can appear multiple times in the sequence if it's not consecutive.

For this sample: `"2x3+2x6+1x3"`

```
import Data.List

countDelta :: [[a]] -> [(Int,a)]
countDelta [] = []
countDelta [[]] = []
countDelta ( (y:zs) : (bs) ) =  (length zs + 1, y) : countDelta bs

groupByDelta :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
groupByDelta (xs) = countDelta ( group [b-a | (a:b:_) <- tails xs] )

printTuples :: [(Int, Int)] -> String
printTuples [] = ""
printTuples [(x,y)] = show x ++ "x" ++ show y
printTuples (x:xs) = printTuples [x] ++ "+" ++ printTuples xs

getSequenceLogic :: [Int] -> String
getSequenceLogic [] = ""
getSequenceLogic [x] = printTuples [(1,0)]
getSequenceLogic (xs) = printTuples (groupByDelta xs)
```

Sample call:

```
getSequenceLogic [100,103,106,112,118,121]
```

I get the expected result but is there any obvious error?

Comment: What's the expected output for a single element list?

Comment: I've made the choice to print "1x0" in this case.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to simplify a pair of your functions:

**`countDelta`**

```
countDelta = map (\(x:xs) -> (length xs + 1, x))
```

In fact most of the logic in your `countDelta` was just reinventing `map`, so actually using `map` makes it much easier.

**`ShowTuples`**

(You named it `printTuples` but it does not **print** the tuples, printing to the screen is an action, while this function is pure, so I named it `showTuples` as `show` is conventionally used in Haskell when a `String` is the output)

```
import Data.List

showTuples = intercalate "+" . map (\(x, y) -> (show x ++ "x" ++ show y))
```

Here you were just putting "x" in between the two elements of each tuple and "+" in between the tuples. Half of the code was reinventing map, the other half `intercalate` using these built-ins makes the code much shorter and self-explanatory.

**`getSequenceLogic`**

A minor simplification only here: you can drop the `[]` case as the `xs` case already handles it correctly:

```
getSequenceLogic [x] = showTuples [(1,0)]
getSequenceLogic xs = showTuples (groupByDelta xs)
```

Comment: Also: `countDelta = map (length &&& head)` but that is more advanced using `Control.Arrow` so I did not include that in the answer. Still note how nicely it expresses that we want a tuple containing the length of the list first, the head second.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that your special case

> ```
> getSequenceLogic [x] = printTuples [(1,0)]
> ```

is justified.  If `[100, 103]` is to be summarized as `"1x3"`, then don't think that `[100]` should be `"1x0"`.  I would consider an empty string to be a reasonable summary of `[100]`.

---

When possible, you want to avoid explicit recursion in favour of higher-level operations.  A solution like this is much more compact:

```
import Data.List (group, intercalate)

diffSummary :: Num a => Eq a => Show a => [a] -> String
diffSummary xs = intercalate "+" $ map text groups
  where
    deltas = map (uncurry (-)) $ zip (tail xs) xs
    groups = map (\g -> (length g, head g)) $ group deltas
    text (len, num) = show len ++ "x" ++ show num
```

Let's start with the type signature.  I suggest avoiding names like "get…", since you can assume that immutability applies everywhere in Haskell.  Also, you can generalize the input type to `Integral a` (normal `Int`s and big `Integer`s) for free.  In fact, the same logic applies to any type that you can subtract, compare for equality, and represent as a string.

Similarly, `printTuples` is misnamed, as it's not actually printing; it's just producing a string representation.  In any case, the function would be better implemented using `Data.List.intercalate`.

`groupDelta` is a bit hairy, as it has pattern subtraction, counting, and recursion all rolled into one.  I've split that up into two lines in my solution: `deltas` and `groups`.

As an illustration of preferring "strategic" thinking over explicit recursion, consider the way `deltas` is computed:

```
xs               = [100,103,106,112,118,121]
tail xs          = [103,106,112,118,121]
zip (tail xs) xs = [(103,100), (106,103), (112,106), (118,112), (121,118)]
map …            = [3, 3, 6, 6, 3]
```

`map (uncurry (-))` just means to perform subtraction for each tuple in the list.  You could also write that as `map (\(a, b) -> a - b)`.

Similarly, when defining `groups`, I avoid recursion by using `map`.